# Sonarqube scan takes entire code or just the hashes

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Currently our sonarqube server is installed in ap-south-1 and we want to scan java code and the Jenkins server resides in us-East-1. Currently peering is established between us-East-1 and  ap-south.
The question here is when Jenkins server that is running mvn sonar:sonar on remote sonar host which is in ap-south-1, is it transmitting the entire code snapshot to sonarqube server or just the hashes of the code are being transmitted to sonarqube server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hash".  When the scan is completed, you can inspect the results of the scan, which includes the source text that was scanned, which will include the entire contents of all the source files.

Comment: So the sonar scanner, in my case maven goal from Jenkins transmits the entire source code java file to sonarqube server ? For example open source software scans like nexus iq or whitesource they never read your code they only transmit encrypted snippets of your source code files.

Comment: Those tools have different purposes. For people to understand issues or test coverage in source files, it's impossible to know what portion of the file would not be necessary.

Comment: So my objective here is not transmit entire source code to ap-south-1 and it should stay in us-East-1 due to compliance reasons but unfortunately the sonarqube server is in ap_south-1 any other workaround you can think of to mitigate this problem apart from spinning up sonarqube server in us-East-1 ?

Comment: Seems like the only solution to that problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing your insight !